# Laravel - ToDateString() Behaves abnormally on Live Server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this code:

Controller

```php
public function index()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;

    $leaverequests = HrLeaveRequest::where('company_id', $userCompany)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();

    $incompleteCount = $leaverequests->filter(function ($item) {
        return (
            $item->leave_status == 2 ||
            $item->leave_status == 3 ||
            $item->leave_status == 4
        );
      })
        ->count(); 
    $currentstatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')
        ->where('is_resumption_activated', 1)
        ->whereIn('leave_status', array(3, 4))
        ->where('resumption_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->first();

    return view('leave.employee_leave_requests.index')
        ->with([
            'leaverequests' => $leaverequests,
            'incompleteCount' => $incompleteCount
        ])
        ->with('currentstatus', $currentstatus);       
}
```

Model:

```php
protected $dates = [
    'resumption_date',
];
```

View

```html
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        @can('leave_request_create')
            @if (! $leaverequests->count() || $currentstatus)

        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route("leave.employee_leave_requests.create") }}">
                    Add Leave Request
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
            @elseif (! $currentstatus)
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">

        </div>
            @endif 
        @endcan

    </div>
</div>
```

The Purpose is to make the "Add Leave Request" when the condition is fulfilled. I tested it on my Windows Local System, and it works fine.

But when I deployed to Linux Ubuntu server, the "Add Leave Request" remains hidden even when the condition is fulfilled.

But when I removed this code:

```
where('resumption_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
```

from the Linux server, it becomes visible (it works).

PHP Version for both local sytem and Ubuntu server is PHP-7.3.

How do I get this resolved.

Comment: If you'd like people to take their time to look at your code, please do take the time to format it to be easily readable. Following PSR-12 guidelines is good practice for your codebase anyway.

Comment: It looks like it should work; are you sure the same data is present in both? First thing I'd change in that line is to use `where('resumption_date', '<=', now())` as Laravel handles conversion.  `whereIn` would be a less verbose way of generating `$incompleteCount`. And why two different calls to `with()` on the view, both with different syntaxes instead of just using one call with `compact()`?

Comment: If you think that `toDateString()` is behaving "abnormally" it seems like it should be easy to fire up `artisan tinker` and run `now()->toDateString()` on both systems...